# Splitting sound with an extended desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have access to a second monitor and USB headphones. I also have Apple EarPods. I wondered if you could split audio, so say audio from a film being displayed on the monitor comes out from the USB headphones and the audio from something playing on my PC screen comes out of my Apple EarPods(the ones with the headphone jack). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who also has this question, I have since found a way to do this in Windows, without using any third party software. Please bear in mind that I am using Windows 10 and the steps may differ or you might not be able to do this with another version. Here are the steps:

1. Open the settings app
2. Navigate to: **System** → **Sound** then scroll down and click on **advanced sound options**.
3. Here, you can adjust sound settings for each application and select different outputs if you have multiple speakers connected. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to split audio between the built-in speakers and my headphones, but this  setting could be very useful for if you have maybe an HDMI or USB audio device connected like in my case.

If this is unclear, or if you have found a way to split audio between built-in speakers and headphones, please comment. Hope this was helful:)

Answer (score 0):

The donationware
[VB-CABLE Virtual Audio Device](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/)
should be useful here.

This product allows the separation of audio sources and sinks and their
virtual "cabling" together.

You can find more information in:

- [How to Setup Virtual Audio Cables](https://www.golightstream.com/handbook/how-to-setup-virtual-audio-cables/)
- [Virtual Audio Cables and Streaming](https://nicarras.com/virtual-audio-cables-streaming/)
- [Playing Music Through Skype Using Virtual Audio Cable](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/sam-virtual-audio-cable-predicament.1153461/)
  has the example of setting up this configuration:

[image]